# Read json from a file using AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I have some code that I want to read some json from a file into a string , and then use it inside a AngularJS application.

right now the below code gives me the error, any idea how i would do this?

```
angular.js:11594 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.html:14)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4182)
    at z.instance (angular.js:8441)
    at angular.js:7693
    at s (angular.js:331)
    at v (angular.js:7692)
    at g (angular.js:7075)
    at angular.js:6954
    at angular.js:1451
    at l.$eval (angular.js:14384)



<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCPtAHujMTGlcHKbuwjDU4tx666iZICTXg"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
    app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
        var fs ;

        this.http.get("./points.json").subscribe(data => {
         console.log('data', data.text());
        })
        $scope.Markers = data.text(); //fs.readFileSync('./points.json').toString().split("\n");
        //Setting the Map options.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.controller('MyController',['$scope', '$http', function ($scope , $http) {

```
        $http.get("./points.json").success(data => {
            console.log('data', data);
        })
    }])
```

try this

Comment: Hey Thanks! Vignesh!  I get this error now though ReferenceError: '$http' is not defined

Comment: Vignesh Nayak  whoops sorry I got it I missed the app.controller part